# Why doesnt this background image display on jsfiddle?

Tags: css, background-image

I am having a problem with a background image appearing. check out my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Jey5/2/) and tell me what i am missing?

```
<div id="postcard-container">
<div id="postcard">
    <div id="postcard-title">
        <h1>Milkweed</h1>

    </div>
    <div id="postcard-sub">What is Milk weed? Sign up to Find out</div>
    <div id="postcard-email">
        <hr>Email capture situation</div>
    <div id="postcard-social"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
background-image: url(...) no-repeat center center fixed;
```

to

```
background: url(...) no-repeat center center fixed;
```